# Multipurpose variables in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I run game servers and wrote a Node.js bot to send/receive chat messages from/to Discord to enable communication between them.
Now I want to integrate it's functionality to receive the latest logs from the game to Discord.
I have managed to make it work for a single player but now I want to make it work for several players.
I have three variables: channelID, server, playerID.

So, my question is what's the best method to have multiple arrays of ChannelID which will contain multiple server values and playerID values to be processed by a single function?

My current working code:

```
var channelID = "channel1";
var server = "server1";
var playerID = "player1";
//Last log message is stored in Webdis
var webdisURL = "http://127.0.0.1:7379/GET/" + server + playerID;

setInterval(() => lastLog(webdisURL, function(body) {
    Object.keys(body).forEach(e => result = `${body[e]}`);
    client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send(result);
}), 3000);

function lastLog(webdisURL, callback) {
    request({
        url: webdisURL,
        json: true
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            callback(body);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: best method compared to what? Sharing your code would not be such a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

So I have managed to do it like this:

```
var webdisURL = "http://127.0.0.1:7379/GET/";

class Players {
    constructor(players, channelID) {
        players = players.split(',');
        players.forEach(getPlayers);

        function getPlayers(value) {
            var playerName = value.split(":")[0];
            var playerSRV = value.split(":")[1];
            var playerID = value.split(":")[2];
            var getLogURL = webdisURL + playerSRV + playerID;
            var result;
            var previousResult;
            setInterval(() => lastLog(getLogURL, function (body) {
                Object.keys(body).forEach(e => result = `${body[e]}`);
                if (result !== previousResult) {
                    client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send("[" + playerName + "] - [" + playerSRV + "]: " + result);
                    previousResult = result;
                }
            }), 3000);

            function lastLog(getLogURL, callback) {
                request({
                    url: getLogURL,
                    json: true
                }, function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                        callback(body);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

// "playerName1:playerSRV1:playerID1,playerName2:playerSRV2:playerID2", "channelID"
let playerTeam1 = new Players("Perseus:myServer1:ID1", "channel1");
let playerTeam2 = new Players("Another Player:myServer2:ID1,Another Player2:myServer3:ID1", "channel2");
```

Example Output:

```
[Perseus] - [myServer1]: Day 153, 11:59:43: Your 'Campfire' was auto-decay destroyed!
[Another Player] - [myServer2]: Day 153, 11:59:43: Your 'Campfire' was auto-decay destroyed!
[Another Player2] - [myServer3]: Day 153, 11:59:43: Your 'Campfire' was auto-decay destroyed!
```

Does it look OK? I'll appreciate any suggestions for improvement.